# Почему - опешивают?

Tags: этимология

Опешить - это значит растеряться. Слово явно произошло от "стать пешим", "спешиться". Но как одно относится к другому?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опешить буквально — «сбросить с коня».
Опешить - опешу, опешишь ( •разг. ). Прийти в замешательство от неожиданности, удивления или испуга. 
Вот едешь ты на коне, и вдруг тебя кто-то сбрасывает с него. Неожиданно. Вот ты и опешил во всех смыслах этого слова.

Comment: Ну да, конечно. Больше всего опешивали на Куликовской битве. Там было не "вдруг", а в страшном бою. "Опешить" - смерти подобно. А уж потом от этого "опешить" пошли метастазы.

Answer (score 0):

Опашъ (от слова *пах*), — задняя часть тела у зверей и людей. Летописец (Хроногр. Избор. 211) так о нашествии поляков на Россию в начале XVII в. выразился: *злопыхательную их опаш на христианский род устави*.

Опешить — присесть, испугавшись.

Answer (score -1):

Все ссылаются на древнерусский, который в любом случае не древнее латинского и его производного - итальянского. Pesce (пеше) - ит. РЫБА. Опешить, соответственно - онеметь (от чего-либо), потерять дар речи (на мгновение). Это не то, что ошеломить (дать чем-то по шлему) - после чего человек находится в смятении. Опешивают именно на мгновение, переживая нечто вылезающее за рамки понимания. Короткий ступор. Это состояние может перерасти в ступор, а может же опешиванием на мгновение и закончится, после того как сознание смирится с новой картиной мира.

Comment: Опешивание матки - термин старый русский, описывается в "Краткой энциклопедии пчеловодства" на стр. 251 (раздел книги "От бортничества к пчеловодству", ТЕРРА-Книжный клуб, Москва,

Comment: А какое отношение итальянский имеет к русскому выражению? Давайте в китайском какое слово найдём - он еще древнее.